# Focusout event not working on firefox when browser don't have focus

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I'm executing some tests after updating all my libraries to the last version like webdrivermanager (v 2.1.0) and selenium-java (v 3.8.1).

Everything was right when I execute them on Chrome, but after testing on firefox i got an issue.

I'm executing

```
myElement.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
```

But i'snt working just on firefox.
After some digging on other forums it's seems that this problem is recurrent in some firefox versions.

Anyone already got this issue?

Edit¹:
I found that the problem is when using firefox, 'focusout' event is not firing when Firefox window is not really on focus.
That is a problem because I run test's in parallel, even when I'm debugging with IDEA on focus the event doesn't fire.

I got no error output when this happen. It's just dont fire 'focusout' javascript event.

I'm using: 
selenium-java version 3.8.1,
Firefox version 57.0.4 (640bits),
geckodriver version 0.19.1.

Comment: What is that which you have `got an issue`? Update the question with the error trace logs.

Comment: I tried sendKyes(Keys.TAB) on Firefor 57.0.4,  geckodriver 0.19.1 and selenium-standalone-server 3.8.1.  it worked well with Protractor script.  So your issue should not come from that three stuff.  I have a question about our webdrivermanager v2.1.0,  from my observe, this version should not support to download geckodriver 0.19.1. And the latest version is 12.0.6,  2.1.0 is too old.  Please give error message if there is.

Comment: I edited the main message. @DebanjanB there is no error output, it just dont fire focusout event on javascript end when the browser don't have focus.

Comment: @yong I updated the main topic with more information, after some debugging I found that the problem is browser focus, but I still unable to find a reasonable solution.

Comment: Same here. [Either switch to Chrom*, or handle focus and blur manually](https://makandracards.com/makandra/12661-how-to-solve-selenium-focus-issues#firefox-dealing-with-lost-focusblur-events).